# Convert a Pandas DataFrame into a list

Tags: python, pandas

How do I go from a data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10), 'b': range(10, 20), 'c': range(20, 30)})
```

that looks like:

```
   a   b   c
0  0  10  20
1  1  11  21
2  2  12  22
3  3  13  23
4  4  14  24
5  5  15  25
6  6  16  26
7  7  17  27
8  8  18  28
9  9  19  29
```

and convert it into a list:    `['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
list(np.reshape(df.values, -1, order='F'))
```

Your df has a shape of (10,3), and you want a shape of (30,). You can achieve this with numpy's reshape.

`-1` is simply a shortcut for `(30,)` in this instance.

`order='F'` ensures that you get values "column-wise," as was presented in your desired output.

Using NumPy methods via [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html), you can use:

```
df.values.reshape(-1, order='F').tolist()
```

Comment: Or `df.values.reshape(-1, order='F').tolist()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine there is probably a better way, but the following will work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0, 10), 'b': range(10, 20), 'c': range(20, 30)})

mylist = list()
for i in df.columns:
    mylist += map(str, df[i].values.tolist())
print(mylist)
```

Output:

> ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12',
>   '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23',
>   '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29']